# listview not scrolling under relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_images"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/approvals_claimitems_reject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:onClick="onClickFeature"
        android:src="@drawable/claim_reject" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/approvals_claimitems_approve"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/approvals_claimitems_reject"
        android:onClick="onClickFeature"
        android:src="@drawable/claim_approve" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_images"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customshape" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/middle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approvals_claim_item_submittedby"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="submitted by"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approvals_claim_item_name"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/approvals_claim_item_submittedby"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approvals_claim_item_currency"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/approvals_claim_item_name"
            android:text="currency"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approvals_claim_item_amount"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/approvals_claim_item_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/approvals_claim_item_currency"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="amount"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/approvals_claim_item_date"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/approvals_claim_item_currency"
            android:text="date"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/middle"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#b5b5b5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_line" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/activity_exp_claimitems_listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:listSelector="#dddddd" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This listview is not scrolling. Scrollview is builtin for listview but its not scrolling. Thanks in advance

Comment: i tried your layout. it does scroll.

Comment: then post the relevant one

Comment: yeah already posted the relevant one

Comment: tried this also it does scroll

Comment: I did the crap `listview.setEnabled(false);`
Thats why its not scrolling. Anyway thanks Mr.Raghunandan